# How to use tocloft package to customize the space between figure number and title?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

My settings is as follows:

```
  \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\songti\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\loflabel\hspace*{0.4em}}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnumb}{\hfill\hspace*{1.0em}}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\rm\zihao{-4}}
  \setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{-2pt}
  \listoffigures
```

The output is as follows (`_` represent blank space):

> Fig 1____xxxxxxxx.......................1
>
> Fig 2____xxxxxxxx....................2
>
> Fig 100__xxxxxxx.....................100

But, what I want is like this:

> Fig 1__xxxxxxxx.......................1
>
> Fig 2__xxxxxxxx.......................2
>
> Fig 100__xxxxxxx.....................100

How should I do with `tocloft` package?

Comment: For future reference, consider posting a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that the community can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Specifically, there is no need to include font-related macros (since that doesn't pertain to the current problem), nor do you include what `\loflabel` is defined as...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) still sets the figure number inside a box of fixed width. That's why you achieve (by default) a left-alignment of the figure captions in the LoF. Here's the (re)definition:

```
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{% 
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
```

The `\hb@xt@\@tempdima{..}` sets a box of width `\@tempdima` - specified by `\cftnumwidth` as part of the list entry construction.

In order to achieve the layout you want, you need to adjust the `\numberline` macro and remove its boxed nature. Below I've created `\cftlofnumberline` which is very similar to the traditional `\numberline` created by `tocloft`, only it removes the fixed-width boxing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\loflabel}{Fig}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\loflabel\hspace*{0.4em}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnumb}{\hspace*{1em}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cftlotnumberline}[1]{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\@cftasnumb}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\numberline\cftlotnumberline
\listoffigures
\endgroup

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{First figure}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{99}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{Last figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the localized scope of the redefinition (via a `\let`) of `\numberline`. You might want a different formatting for your ToC or LoT.